# SSP for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, shared-service-provider, certificate, service, 70-667

As far as I know SSP (Share Service Provider) is a thing of SharePoint 2007 and in SharePoint 2010 it has been redesigned as SharePoint 2010 service application, but I came across this question online if someone can tell me if its right (I have seen it at few places with different wordings)

Question is,

[image]

Choices are,

[image]

Can someone tell me if SSP is related to SharePoint 2010 "in any way."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shared Service Provider is a SP 2007 feature. In 2010 it was replaced/renamed with service applications.

The MSDN article [What's New: Service Application Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537258%28v=office.14%29.aspx) states:

> The Service Application Framework replaces the Shared Services Provider in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007.

The main benefit of the Service Application Framework over the Shared Service Provider is the ability to manage each application individually, allowing for the service application to be used by a single farm or multiple farms as well as making it easier to scale the service application based on use.

Comment: Also, the main reason why it's now called Service Applications is because Sharepoint 2010 was built with .NET 3.5 which uses WCF Service Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Question I mentioned in my post isn't legitimate, its a wrong question which cannot have any right answer.

Hope it helps other preparing for 70 - 667 exam.

Comment: Right. You just can't configure an SSP for SharePoint 2010 whatever the Service Pack. Only the Service Applications.

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment?